# Twitter Bootstrap center elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for `Twitter Bootstrap` examples and do not understand how all elements [in this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/) are centered? Using what tag or style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `.container` div is centered using auto margins.

```
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Also `.jumbotron` has

```
text-align: center;
```

attribute which centers the the child 'Sign up' button.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the helper classes in bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)

Center content blocks
Set an element to display: block and center via margin. Available as a mixin and class.

```
<div class="center-block">...</div>

    // Classes
    .center-block {
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }

 // Usage as mixins
.element {
  .center-block();
}
```